# Modeling hierarchy in OpenGL

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, modeling

I'm currently learning OpenGL and got my first bunch of geometry and textures displayed.

Now I'm trying to set-up a parent-child hierarchy model between different graphic actors.
I understand that it's usually implemented like this:

```
void Draw(){
    glPushMatrix();
    <apply all transformations>
    <draw this model>
    <for each child c of this actor:>
        c.Draw();
    glPopMatrix();
}
```

This way the children will inherit all transformations of the parent (scale, position, rotation).
But sometimes I'd like only certain transformations to be applied (e.g. a special-effects actor should move with it's parent, but not use it's parent's rotation while a helmet actor wants to inherit all transformations).

The idea I've come up with is passing the transformation parameters that should be applied to the drawing functions:

```
class Actor{
    Vec3 m_pos, m_rot, m_scale; //This object's own transformation data
    std::vector<Actor*> m_children;

    void Draw(Vec3 pos, Vec3 rot, Vec3 scale){
        (translate by pos) //transform by the given parent data
        (rotate around rot)
        (scale by scale)

        glPushMatrix(); //Apply own transformations
        (translate by m_pos)
        (rotate around m_rot)
        (scale by m_scale)
        (draw model)
        glPopMatrix(); //discard own transformations

        for( Actor a : m_children ){
            glPushMatrix();
            a.Draw( pass m_pos, m_rot and/or m_scale depending on what the current child wants to inherit );
            glPopMatrix();
        }
    }
}

void StartDrawing(){
    glLoadIdentity();
    //g_wold is the "world actor" which everything major is attached to.
    g_world.Draw( Vec3(0,0,0), Vec3(0,0,0), Vec3(0,0,0) );
}
```

(Pseudo-code. Might be errorneous, but should convey the idea.)

But that seems rather untidy and looks like much more work load for the program (since there'd be a ton of additional vector math).

I've read a bit about hierarchical modeling, but all literature about it seems to assume that every child always wants to inherit all parent properties.

Are there any better ways of doing so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A side note first: The matrix stack is deprecated in recent OpenGL versions and users should control the transformations themselves.

The problem you are facing comes up with every kind of OpenGL state that you are using in your rendering graph. A common way (as for example in OpenSceneGraph) to solve this is to define an additional property for each state which defines if the subgraph overrides a property in its children. In turn children can protect their state from being overridden through a parent. This works well for every kind of OpenGL state.

Your case seems a little odd. Often transformations are intended to be applied to the whole subgraph. Although this scheme could work here as well.